# Beautiful Soup is pulling in non existent tags Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I am running a BS on a page with job listings, everything is working fine apart from one line. It is printing tags for some reason. The tags are /n and \n

However, when I word it looking to get each individual box, it works fine. See below code and outputs

```
print(jobs[2].find('h2').get_text())
print(jobs[2].find(class_='company-title-name').get_text())
```

> Systems Analyst
>
> Lex Consultancy

Then when I loopo through all the results, the company_name list has the random tags that are not in the inspect element. I have left a 2nd item in to show its not happening on that one

```
job_title = [job.find('h2').get_text() for job in jobs]
company_name = [job.find(class_='company-title-name').get_text() for job in jobs]

print(job_title)
print(company_name)
```

> ```
> ['Business Analyst/Web Analyst (Digital Experience/e-Commerce)', 'Data Migration Consultant - SQL , Oracle, .net   Permanent Role',
> ```
>
> 'Systems Analyst', 'Sales Operations Analyst']
>       ['\nAscension\n', '\nCpl Technology\n', '\nLex Consultancy\n', '\nGilligan Black Recruitment\n']

Below is the code where they are stored from the page inspect element

```
<div class="serp-title">
   <a jobid="1863378" href="https://www.jobs.ie/ApplyForJob.aspx?Id=1863378" title="Systems Analyst">
       <h2>Systems Analyst</h2>
   </a>
   <span>
     <text class="company-title-name">
     <a href="/Lex-Consultancy/">Lex Consultancy</a>
     </text>
   </span>
</div>
```

Is anyone aware of why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about the `\n` characters showing up?

Comment: at least in real html you make a difference between a elementNode and a textNode. Both are children but the latter is in 99% if cases not what you want. Not sure about BS but I can imagine this is going on under the hood as you call a `get_text` function. If there is anywhere text not inside a elementNode, you probably get that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\n` characters are linefeeds, and the reason you're getting them is that they're in your source document.

You're getting the tag with `class='company-title-name'` which is this one:

```
 <text class="company-title-name">
 <a href="/Lex-Consultancy/">Lex Consultancy</a>
 </text>
```

and then you're getting just the text, let's remove the inner tags:

```
 <text class="company-title-name">
 Lex Consultancy
 </text>
```

Do you see the linefeeds? One is right after the ">" on the first line and the other is after "Consultancy".

Just in case it's not entirely clear, this is what the HTML would look like without the linefeeds:

```
 <text class="company-title-name">Lex Consultancy</text>
```

Try using `strip()` and `rstrip()`.